# How do I add an analytics label to data messages with the java Firebase Admin SDK?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics, firebase-admin

As of July 1, Firebase requires the addition of labels to messages in order for analytics to show about the number of data message sends etc.

> 'Starting Monday, 1 July 2019, you will be able to filter data by an analytics label.
>   Data messages sent without an analytics label might not be represented in this dashboard after that date.'

The problem is that the link to the documentation provided by firebase [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?authuser=0#adding_analytics_labels_to_messages), does not help. It only refers to HTTP requests whilst I am using the Firebase Admin SDK running on a Java app engine instance.

This is the barebones of the code I am using to currently send data messages. How can I adapt this to send my messages with an analytics label?

```java
Message message = Message.builder()
                .putData("data",data)
                .setToken(deviceID)
                .build();


        String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found it:

```
Message message = Message.builder()
    .putData("data",data)
    .setFcmOptions(FcmOptions.withAnalyticsLabel("MyLabel"))
    .setToken(deviceID)
    .build();
```

I can see messages in Firebase console -> Reports -> Data tab.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Upgrade  SDK if you don't find this method. I am using 6.10

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the [commit history of the `messaging` section of the SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/commits/master/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/messaging), it seems like support for this header has not been added to the Firebase Admin SDK for Java yet.

You might want to file a feature request or (even better) open a PR. I left a comment on this existing [feature request](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/issues/137), which seemed most relevant to what you're asking.