# How do I add an analytics label to data messages with the Javascript (or typescript) Firebase Admin SDK?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase-cloud-messaging, label, send

I want set a label in the message.And I read the official document [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?authuser=0#adding_analytics_labels_to_messages) and similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56920853/how-do-i-add-an-analytics-label-to-data-messages-with-the-java-firebase-admin-sd).

But I can't figure out how to write it in javascript.

my code here:

```
const message = {
    notification: {
        title: "myTitle",
        body: "myBody"
    },
    condition: "!('TopicA' in topics)",
    AnalyticsLabel : "mylabel"             <=== something like this?
};
const response = await admin.messaging().send(message);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the trick...

```
const message = {
    notification: {
        title: "myTitle",
        body: "myBody"
    },
    condition: "!('TopicA' in topics)",
    fcmOptions: {
        analyticsLabel : "MyLabel"
    }
};
```